# JavaScript HTTP requests fail on amazon ec2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, axios

I am running a node express server on Amazon ec2 instance. I can connect to the website on my local machine from within the browser, and can view pages with only local files, but when accessing a page that makes an external HTTP request, it just hangs. I figure it has something to do with my inbound or outbound rules are prohibiting it somehow, but don't know enough about networking to solve it on my own.

These are the functions that are failing behind the scenes:

```js
const axios = require('axios').default;
const freelancer = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://www.freelancer.com/api/',
    headers: {
        'freelancer-oauth-v1': process.env.FREELANCER_TOKEN
    }
});

/* Get User By Id */
async function getUserById(user_id) {
    const result = await freelancer.get(`/users/0.1/users/${user_id}/`)
    return result.data.result;
}

const GitHub = require('github-api');
const gh = new GitHub({
    username: process.env.GHUSER,
    password: process.env.GHPASS
});
const getRepos = async function () {
    const user = await gh.getUser();
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        await user.listStarredRepos(function (err, repos) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(repos);
        });
    });
}
```

My routers look like this:

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const freelancer = require('../service/Freelancer');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  const reviews = await freelancer.getMyReviews();
  const self = await freelancer.getSelfData();

  res.render('contact', {
    header: 'Check out all my reviews!',
    lead: '',
    paragraphtext: 'Your review could be next on this list!',
    reviews,
    self
  });
});
```

Comment: Making requests from where? From instance, to the instance? You need to provide more details. Exactly what is your setup, what are you doing, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Pretty simple question, I'm running a node server, making calls with axios when it hits a router. Look I updated so you can see the code.

Comment: Some services are explicitly blocking IP ranges for AWS. Could be one of this situations. Can you independently verity that the `www.freelancer.com/api` if you just curl it from the instance for example?

Comment: Getting errors like this: 
```javascript
curl: (7) Failed to connect to www.github.com port 443: Connection timed out.
```
It says when I try using no https: `"301 moved permanently."`
So I add https and it just hangs.

Comment: Oh man that fixed it. I added new rules for HTTPS connections. @Marcin thanks for giving me that lead!

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by using HTTP for `www.github.com`. The **solution** was to use HTTPS.